# mysqldump.exe: Error 1034: Index for table 'assets' is corrupt; try to repair it when dumping table 'assets' at row 1960363

Tags: mysql

I get this error after saving database below:

mysqldump.exe: Error 1034: Index for table 'assets' is corrupt; try to repair it when dumping table 'assets' at row 1960363

How can i fix this as not want to lose database but unable to save database cause of this error. Can you tell me easy fix to try to get this fix to be able to save database?

Am using Maria database 10.5

Thanks

Comment: [Knowledge Base » MariaDB Server Documentation » ... » REPAIR TABLE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/repair-table/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this c# function to backup you database

```
 public static void Backup()
    {
        string constring = "server=localhost;user=root;pwd=****;database=databaseName;";
        string file= DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("backup dd MMM yyyy HH mm")+".sql";
        string fileNme= Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)+"\\"+fileName;
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
        {

            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();
                     mb.ExportToFile(file); 
      
                    conn.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Sauvegarde éffectuée avec succès !!!","Infrmation",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

for more informations about MySqlBackup visit this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html)